# Domain mapping of appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, url, dns

[image: This is my appengine acounnt domain setting page]
[image: These are the instructions provided to map url]
[image]

Please** help me ** the domain is not mapping still ..is that the cname setting in this dns is correct ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems incorrect to me... why do you have 4 repeated entries of www on both left and right side?

It should be something like:

www on the left side,  type cname, then content should be ghs.googlehosted.com

Comment: I have changed the as u said and i re-posted above. Please check Is it correct or not?

Comment: works for me, DNS need time to get updated, here's my ping result to your site:

C:\Users\Lawrence>ping www.setitup.in
Pinging ghs.googlehosted.com [74.125.128.121] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 74.125.128.121: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=50
Reply from 74.125.128.121: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=50
Reply from 74.125.128.121: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=50
Reply from 74.125.128.121: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=50

Comment: you may try to "flush your dns" / restart computer , or just wait 12-24 hours and it should work